# Collect values from a spreadsheet, look for those values in a string and replace

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, replace

The values in my spreadsheet are these:
[image]

```
/2021/
/20212022/
/2022/
/20222023/
/2023/
```

To try to find these values in a string and then replace with `/@@@@/` I tried creating a map:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('One')
var liga = 'https://int.testestest.com/national/united-states/mls/2022/regular-season/r66725/'
var years = sheet.getRange('One!A10:A14').getValues().flat();
var mapObj = {one: years[0],two: years[1],three: years[2],four: years[3],five: years[4]};

var liga_substitute = liga.replace(/\b(?:one|two|three|four|five)\b/gi, matched => mapObj[matched]);

var liga_final_subs = liga_substitute.replace('one','/@@@@/').replace('two','/@@@@/').replace('three','/@@@@/').replace('four','/@@@@/').replace('five','/@@@@/')
```

But the result after substitution remains the same:

```
https://int.testestest.com/national/united-states/mls/2022/regular-season/r66725/
```

My final expected result is:

```
https://int.testestest.com/national/united-states/mls/@@@@/regular-season/r66725/
```

And in `var liga_final_subs =` exist the risk of finding these parts of text in the wrong places and replacing what shouldn't.

How should I go about doing this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you trying to gain. Here is the code that does the job (I hope):

```js
var liga = 'https://int.testestest.com/national/united-states/mls/2022/regular-season/r66725/'

var years = [
    '/2021/',
    '/20212022/',
    '/2022/',
    '/20222023/',
    '/2023/',
];

var liga_final_subs = liga;

years.forEach(x => liga_final_subs = liga_final_subs.replace(x, '/@@@@/'));

console.log(liga_final_subs);
```

Comment: That's exactly it, change all values to ```/@@@@/```, thanks for support @YuriKhristich

Comment: Actually, I suspect, it can be done a little bit more efficiently if there are many cells.